# Kubernetes Ingress Controller Deployment loop of replicaset failing

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, replicaset

This weekend I had some problems in production and I need a little help:

On Saturday I received an alert that all the apps in one of my clusters (hosted on Google Cloud) stopped receiving traffic.

I started looking and what happened is that I had a `CrashLoopBackOff` in the creation of the Ingress controller pod.
I tried several things and finally managed to fix it but now although it is working it has stayed in a strange state.

Now I have 2 `replicasets` instead of one, one of them creates the pod correctly and that's why it works but another is still in error loop:

```
NAME                                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-7855         1         1         0       33h
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-7b8b         1         1         1       34h
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-7855               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   397        33h
pod/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-7b8b               1/1     Running            12         34h
```

The strange thing about it is that if I describe the deployment of the ingress controller, I see the following:

```
OldReplicaSets:  nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-7b8b (1/1 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:   nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-7855 (1/1 replicas created)
```

As you can see, the new `Replicaset` is the one that is creating the failed pods and it is the old one that works correctly.
My first idea was to restart the deployment by doing `kubectl -n service rollout restart deployment ${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}` but now I am afraid that the status that remains is 2 `Replicasets` failing both ...

Also, I cannot delete the `Replicasets` that is failing because it is created automatically again with the same problem.

The Docker image is the same for both `Replicasets` too: `nginx/nginx-ingress:1.10.0`

So my problem is that I cannot clean the "corrupt" `Replicasets`. Any idea will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any corresponding message on why the new `replicaSet` is failing? Any logs from `$ kubectl describe` or `$ kubectl logs`?

Comment: Good point. Comparing the `describe` output from both `replicaset` I've noticed that the one failing has an extra `annotation` that seems to be invalid. I'm gonna try to remove that annotation and check if it works that way. Thanks!